# MS Word VBA Find Variable-Length Pattern String

Tags: vba, ms-word

**Question:** Is there a way to specify a repeating pattern of variable but bounded length in the Find.Text argument?

**Background:**

I have a collection of Word documents, each containing several hundred pages of numbered text blocks. I want to copy each block of text into its own cell in a spreadsheet, but the text blocks aren't in Ordered or Multi-Level Lists and each block of text may contain multiple paragraphs, so I can't simply select and copy each paragraph in the document. To work around this, I've tried to use the Range.Find method to locate two adjacent number headings and copy all the characters between them. For testing purposes, I'm using the following sample document:

[image: Test Document]

The paragraph header numbers can be 2-5 levels deep, with 1-2 digits in each level (i.e. "x.x." through "xx.xx.xx.xx.xx."). I'm using a wildcard search of the form "xx.xx.", relying on the placement of the decimal points to identify the headers. Here's my code:

```
'Open the Word document
    Doc = CStr(folderPath & objFile.Name)
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Doc)
    Set wRange = wDoc.Range
    RngEnd = wRange.End
        
    'Search for text block
        With wRange
            Do While i < 7 And subRngStart2 < RngEnd
                With .Find  'Search for starting keyword
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Text = "[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}."
                    .Forward = True
                    '.Format = True
                    .MatchWildcards = True
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Execute
                End With
                
                If .Find.Found = True Then
                    subRngStart1 = wRange.Start 'Mark starting position
                    wRange.SetRange Start:=subRngStart1 + 6, End:=RngEnd 'Reset range starting at end of keyword
                    contentFlag = True
                Else
                    contentFlag = False
                End If
                With .Find  'Search for ending keyword
                    .ClearFormatting
                    .Text = "[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{1,2}."
                    .Forward = True
                    .MatchWildcards = True
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Execute
                End With
                
                If .Find.Found = True Then
                    subRngStart2 = wRange.Start 'Mark ending position
                Else
                    subRngStart2 = RngEnd
                End If
                wRange.SetRange Start:=subRngStart1, End:=subRngStart2 'Set range between first and second keywords
                
                'Copy text in range to Excel
                If contentFlag = True Then
                    Cells(i + 1, 1) = wRange.Text
                End If
                
                wRange.SetRange Start:=subRngStart2 - 3, End:=RngEnd 'Reset range starting at last keyword
                i = i + 1
            Loop
        End With
```

This works fine for headers up to 3 levels but breaks down beyond that: the "Long Headers" example gets split in half because the search thinks the first two levels in the string form a complete text block (Row 7 in the output sample below).

[image: Sample Output]

I could just increase the starting offset (first IF statement, second line) from 6 to 10 to "skip over" long number strings, but this can cause problems with very short headers. I think the *proper* way to fix this is to search for a pattern of the form "xx.xx." which may repeat up to 4 consecutive times. I've tried a couple of variations on the wildcard string to achieve this, including:

```
.Text = "[0-9]{1,2}.*[0-9]{1,2}."
.Text = "[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{0,2}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}."
```

But these either don't do what I want or fail to compile (I'm guessing a min length of zero isn't allowed in wildcard charlists). Is it possible to specify variable-length patterns in Find.Text, or do I need to take a completely different approach?

Comment: You could, of course, use a single wildcard Find expression for all combinations: **^13[0-9.]{1,}*^13[0-9].** then exclude the first & last paragraphs from the output (e.g. .Start = .Start +1, .End = .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Start). For some fairly basic code, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/42332-copy-contents-between-parenthesis-paste-end-document.html